# Как привязать кнопку к popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Помогите пожалуйста написать JS код кнопки для открытия/закрытия самодельного popup окна. Спасибо.

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.popup__text {
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  resize: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.popup__block-send {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.popup__button-send {
  background: url(img/arrow.svg);
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 180px;
  left: 175px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup__close {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -11px;
  left: 90%;
  down: 0px;
  right: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.popup__button-open {
  background: url(img/chat.svg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <form class="popup__form-send">
        <label class="popup__block-send">
              <textarea name="name" class="popup__text" placeholder="Напишите сообщение..."></textarea>
              <button type="submit" class="popup__button-send"></button>
            </label>
      </form>
      <a href="#index" id="popup__close" class="popup__close">-</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="popup__button-open">
      </button>
  <script src="MyScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, Вы ещё вызываете js-скрипт "MyScript.js", верно? Не могли бы Вы и его тоже вставить в вопрос?

Comment: JS без кода вообще, так что толку скидывать особо его и нету.

Comment: Да, кстати, этот код вообще ничего не показывает в консоли (проверено здесь и на JSFiddle). Вы точно уверены, что у Вас всё отображается?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.popup__button-open, #popup__close').forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.popup').classList.toggle("popup_show")));
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.popup_show {
  display: block;
}

.popup__text {
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  resize: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.popup__block-send {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.popup__button-send {
  background: url(img/arrow.svg);
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 180px;
  left: 175px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup__close {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -11px;
  left: 90%;
  right: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.popup__button-open {
  background: url(img/chat.svg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <form class="popup__form-send">
      <label class="popup__block-send">
              <textarea name="name" class="popup__text" placeholder="Напишите сообщение..."></textarea>
              <button type="submit" class="popup__button-send"></button>
            </label>
    </form>
    <a href="#index" id="popup__close" class="popup__close">-</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="popup__button-open">click</button>
```